# How to associate ssh key to heroku account in eclipse i am getting following error

Tags: eclipse, heroku, ssh

i am new to heroku please help me .. :/

We have encountered a problem creating your application: intense-harbor-6816. This could be due to the Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account. To fix this error, you can:  - Associate your SSH key to your Heroku account by going to "Preferences"     OR     - If the SSH Key is correct, restart Eclipse. git@heroku.com:intense-harbor-6816.git: session is down.
during cloning the application from heroku.
Please help me how can i fix it ..?

Answer (score 3):

Try

`ssh-keygen`

and

`heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

and then see if this works

`ssh -vT git@heroku.com`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing Same error and was able to resolve this.

Please check this article to resolve it. [Resolve Error : Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/resolve-error-eclipse-ssh-key-is-not-matching-the-ssh-keys-that-is-associated-with-your-heroku-account/)

Regards,

Jitendra Zaa