# Create Heroku App from Template in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to create a new Heroku App from Template in Spring (Version: 3.3.0.RELEASE) tool. I have loogged succesfully and got proper ssh key loaded in Spring and in herocu web account. Also I have less that 5 projects (not reached the limit), every time i try to start new project and set "Spring MVC & Tomcat application" and click Finish it gives me an error:

```
We have encountered a problem creating your application: shielded-retreat-3014. This could be due to the Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account. To fix this error, you can:

- Associate your SSH key to your Heroku account by going to "Preferences"
    OR    
- If the SSH Key is correct, restart Eclipse.
git@heroku.com:shielded-retreat-3014.git: reject HostKey: heroku.com
```

**EDIT:**

Just after errror the application is getting created on heroku web account.

The same error occurs even I restart Eclipse and try to Import existing project (yes,it see it) "autodetect: Maven" and "General project" does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple although it took me hours to figure it out. The Heroku site is not being added to your known hosts.

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Show view -> Other... -> Git -> Git repositories. From there, clone the repository. Once you clone it, import it from the file menu. Do this since when you clone the repository, it does not add it to the explorer view. Now you should have the Git repository and the explorer view.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved my problem after trying [these solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374030/eclipse-my-ssh-key-does-not-match-the-ssh-key-associated-with-my-heroku-acct) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heroku/s54dYyJaF0M) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239158/how-to-associate-ssh-key-to-heroku-account-in-eclipse-i-am-getting-following-err).

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this same problem and solved it.  I believe the issue is due to not having a known hosts entry for heroku.com.  I am not sure what is the best way to get the needed finger print,  but I solved my problem when i tried to just clone the repo from heroku using Egit.  I got a pop up informing me that heroku.com was not a known host and allowed me to accept the key.  If I recall correctly you normally get this key the first time you try to ssh into a host.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing Same error and was able to resolve this.

[Resolve Error : Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/resolve-error-eclipse-ssh-key-is-not-matching-the-ssh-keys-that-is-associated-with-your-heroku-account/)